# ODataException: There is an unterminated string literal at position X, when a special character is passed as a filter parameter value

Tags: c#, .net, json, odata, httpclient

I am facing an issue while passing a filter parameter value which contains a special character i.e. '#' in odata query. 
Example: "http://100.100.100.44:9999/DataMockService.svc/DataLineItemSet()?$expand=Sales&$filter=SoldTo/ZipCode eq '30931#'&$select=Sales/SalesNumber"

This is throwing the above mentioned error. In the back-end, I have a record which contains '30931#' in ZipCode column. When I remove # from the query, the query executes fine. I even tried encoding the '#' to '%23' but no use. Please help me with a workaround.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Use [HtmlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388364.aspx)

```
var encodedfilter = WebUtility.HtmlEncode(filter);
```

and then send `encodedfilter` as parameter

Comment: Hi @Ikram Turgunbaev. Thank You for the response. I tried the suggested approach, but still the query constructed using this still throws the same error.

Comment: can you share some code? and then we can discuss better